# SQL 5.7 Lead Function

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm struggling emulating a lead function to calculate the difference of (after date - current date)

I'm currently using mysql 5.7 to accomplish this. I have tried looking at various sources on stack overflow but I'm not sure how to get the result.

This is what I want:

[image]

What I currently have now is the same thing without the days column.

I would also like to know how to get a column of dates that grabs the date after the current date.

Comment: It is unclear why the column `days` for row with id=4 does not have the value 4.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (except for the unclear row=4):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table4;
CREATE TABLE table4 (id integer, user_id integer, product varchar(10), `date` date);
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES
  (1,1,'item1','2020-01-01'),
  (2,1,'item2','2020-01-01'),
  (3,1,'item3','2020-01-02'),
  (4,1,'item4','2020-01-02'),
  (5,2,'item5','2020-01-06'),
  (6,2,'item6','2020-01-09'),
  (7,2,'item7','2020-01-09'),
  (8,2,'item8','2020-01-10');
  
  
SELECT 
   id,
   user_id,
   product,
   date,
   (SELECT date FROM table4 t4 WHERE t4.id>t1.id LIMIT 1) x,
   COALESCE(DATEDIFF((SELECT date FROM table4 t4 WHERE t4.id>t1.id LIMIT 1),date),0) as days
FROM table4 t1
```

output:

```
+ ------- + ------------ + ------------ + --------- + ----------- + --------- +
| id      | user_id      | product      | date      | x           | days      |
+ ------- + ------------ + ------------ + --------- + ----------- + --------- +
| 1       | 1            | item1        | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 0         |
| 2       | 1            | item2        | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 1         |
| 3       | 1            | item3        | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 | 0         |
| 4       | 1            | item4        | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-06 | 4         |
| 5       | 2            | item5        | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-09 | 3         |
| 6       | 2            | item6        | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-09 | 0         |
| 7       | 2            | item7        | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-10 | 1         |
| 8       | 2            | item8        | 2020-01-10 |            | 0         |
+ ------- + ------------ + ------------ + ---------- + ---------- + --------- +
```

The column `x` is only here for to see which date is returned from the subquery, and not really needed for the final result.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c69eedc3cef21bfdff51fbf81242e59f)

EDIT: when there are no "gaps" in the numbering of id, you could do this to get a solution which should have more performance:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id,
   t1.user_id,
   t1.product,
   t1.date,
   COALESCE(DATEDIFF(t2.date,t1.date),0) as days
FROM table4 t1
LEFT JOIN table4 t2 on t2.id = t1.id+1
```

I added this to the [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd3dcd91f2d40c897657c719175bad97)

Comment: Thank you so much for this but unfortunately the query takes way to long to load for it to be an efficient query I want to run multiple times.

I'm going to try to use mysql connector and work in python for better solutions.

Comment: @Alban18: you should provide more info, like how many records are in your table and how is it created. It is (almost) impossible to get good performance without knowing these details.

Comment: Hey Luuk,
I'll provide better details next time I ask. This table I'm doing my calculations has just over 1 million records pulled from an existing database in mysql workbench.

For now, I've decided to use Python and doing the calculation in there since it's easier on the application level I believe.